# How we know finger print is changed or new fingerprint is added

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have use Plugin.Fingerprint package in app.

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //var abc = DependencyService.Get<IXEncryptionService>().Encrypt(txtpass.Text.Trim());
        //var ss = DependencyService.Get<IXEncryptionService>().Decrypt(abc);

        var res = await CrossFingerprint.Current.IsAvailableAsync(true);
        if (res)
        {
            var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync("Tap that fingerprint sensor!");
            if (result.Authenticated)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Results are here", "Valid fingerprint found", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Results are here", result.ErrorMessage, "Ok");
            }
        }

    }
```

Is there any way to know the List of fingerprint in mobile and how i know new fingerprint is added in mobile

Comment: I'm afraid that you could not get the list of fingerprint in device .Otherwise,it would be a huge security risk.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK CrossFingerprint does not have such functionality, but you can implement it by yourself.

For your Android project read about [KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException).

For your iOS project you can use [this](https://gist.github.com/Alexander-Alekseev/5d18ba09e0a8afad8819364e3939b782). Just set up `BiometryDomainState` during first login to your application and keep it secret! Use `SecureStorage` for example.

Comment: Don't you think Apple would reject the app because of this? https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/

Comment: I use official SDK, why should Apply reject my app?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514150-evaluatedpolicydomainstate

Comment: Because I am pretty sure you cannot store biometric data as per Apple/Google policies, Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: I do not store biometric **data** in my application. Moreover, I'm not sure that it is possible at all. What I do is I store **state**. If **state** was changed between app launches then either new fingerprint/face was registered or all fingerprints/face were removed.

Comment: For example: I have an application (actually I already have, in both Google and Apple stores, not rejected) that keeps user's data on the phone. It is possible to login to the application using either password or biometrica data. Let's imagine that user's phone was stolen and criminal wants to access secret data. He doesn't know user's password, but he wants to bypass biometric identification. How? He can either delete all registered fingerprints or register a new one. If developers didn't keep previous **state** then criminal will successfully log in.

Comment: And how did the criminal unlock the phone exactly? If he can break Android/iOS's phone lock algo what makes you think your app stands any chance?

Comment: Well, that's a good question, but it's offtopic here, right?

You don't know the application field... I wrote 'criminal', but maybe it will be your colleague that took your unlocked phone when you left the office for a minute?